# NgStyle is not updating in observable complete call back

Tags: angular

I have a an element that I am togelling its heights according to the response of a web call. Initially I made the height style with 0px

```
public voiceCommCockpitHeight = { height: '150px' };
```

The code is like this

```
this.api.get(`${bots_uri}voicecomm/hello?q=${this.commandText.nativeElement.innerText}`).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log('voice command response', response);


        },
        (error) => {

        },
        () => {
           this.voiceCommCockpitHeight = { height: '0px' };
           this.isVoiceCommActive = false;
        }
      )

toggleVoiceCommand(){
    if (this.isVoiceCommActive == false){
      this.voiceCommCockpitHeight = { height: '150px' };
      this.isVoiceCommActive = true;
      this.startMic("#command-text");
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.endMic();
      }, 10000);
    } else {
      this.voiceCommCockpitHeight = { height: '0px' };
      this.isVoiceCommActive = false;
      this.endMic();
    }

  }
```

this is the click function call from the html

```
activateVoiceComm($e) {
    this.toggleVoiceCommand();
  }
```

But the ngStyle's height remains its previous value. If I make it in button click it works. I also tried async pipe but no luck.

Comment: could you include your view

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting values in subscribe's `onCompleted` callback:

```
() => {
  this.voiceCommCockpitHeight = { height: '0px' };
  this.isVoiceCommActive = false;
}
```

**onCompleted**

> An Observable calls this method after it has called onNext for the
>   final time, if it has not encountered any errors.

Take a look [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) for reference.

HttpClient methods returns response and completes. That's why height value *remains* (because of resetting to `'0px'`). You should remove last callback from *subscribe* and place your logic for setting height from response in first callback.

Comment: If I put the ngStyle variable in onNext also and change it does not work. I am not fully clear what you are telling about.

Comment: @DaveB Check my answer now. I edited it to better show what I meant.

Comment: Thats what did but still no luck. It must be something I am doing silly things.

Comment: @DaveB Please provide StackBlitz demo, I will investigate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this is an Angular change detection problem. For a full run-down of how that works, I recommend [this article.](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

---

In short, the callback that runs when the observable emits a value (or completes) is run outside of Angular. So, the Angular framework is unaware that the data backing the view has changed. To fix this, you must manually tell Angular "Hey, things have changed!".

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

doStuff() {
    this.api.get(`${bots_uri}voicecomm/hello?q=${this.commandText.nativeElement.innerText}`).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log('voice command response', response);
        },
        (error) => {
        },
        () => {
           this.voiceCommCockpitHeight = { height: '0px' };
           this.isVoiceCommActive = false;
           this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
        }
      )
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I used it but surprisingly it still does not work.